# Brokering three-party deals in Bohnanza

Tags: bohnanza

I was playing Bohnanza with some family, my brother-in-law kept trying to negotiate three-party trades. I felt like this was against the rules but as long as everyone's trades were planted at the end I let him get away with it.

E.g.

> Mom, I'll give you a red bean if you give sis a soy bean. And sis you give me a garden bean.

Is this against the rules? Should I have stopped him?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All trades must be between the active player and a single player.

Further, any traded beans must be immediately planted, so you cannot receive a bean in trade and then trade away that same bean.

The best you can do is

- give your red bean to Mom (you are allowed to trade something for
  nothing)
- sister gives you a garden bean
- when it is your mother or your sister's turn, hope that they complete the trade; note that there is no obligation to do so.

Comment: Traded beans don't have to be planted *immediately*, but they must be planted by the person who received them, and they must be planted at the end of the current turn. Otherwise, good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Three way direct trades are against the rules. Bob and Carol and each trade with Alice but they can't involve each other. But they wanted to do a three way trade. Bob and Carol could trade with Alice and then on Carol's turn she can continue the deal with Bob and Alice but she's under no obligation game wise to keep the deal.